# how to call convertLead via jsforce

Tags: typescript, salesforce, jsforce

I am trying to call leadConvert function via jsforce lib and not able to setup the soapAPI correctly.

```
import { SoapApi } from "jsforce";
const soapApi = await new SoapApi(conn);
conn.soap.convertLead //has no exported member 'SoapApi'.
```

changed to

```
conn.soap.convertLead(leadConverts, function(err, res) {}
```

Property 'soap' does not exist on type 'Connection'.

I do see soap.js but it can't call to covertLead function. I am running jsforce 1.8 version.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this work in a pretty straightforward manner on both 1.7.1 and 1.8.3 (latest):

```
import jsforce from 'jsforce';

const conn = new jsforce.Connection({loginUrl});
// do login...
// call `convertLead` on conn.soap...
const result = await conn.soap.convertLead(leadConverts);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You can find more doc here: http://jsforce.github.io/jsforce/doc/SoapApi.html#convertLead. Thanks @existdissolve